# Chain a where query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering if there is a way to chain the attrbutes I'm trying to find in a where statement.

```
foo.where( bar.type: 1 )
```

I also tried:

```
foo.where( bar: { type: 1 } )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Rails ActiveRecord chain "where" clauses without multiple queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747106/how-does-rails-activerecord-chain-where-clauses-without-multiple-queries)

Comment: Can you give more information into what you are trying to do? I think you are trying to look for the `joins` method to query on associations..

Comment: Okay.  Sure.  I want to search all of through all 'foos' to find the the ones that have a 'bar' with a 'type' of 1.

Answer (score 4):

If `Foo` is your model, and each instance has an association called `bar`, stored in a table called `bars`, then [Karthik T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1520364/karthik-t)'s advice is what you need:

`Foo.joins(:bar).where(bars: { type: 1 })`

You can find more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

If that doesn't work, you could try updating your question with more specific information about how your models are associated.