# Rails Active Record related topic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm building an app that has a People model that has_and_belongs_to_many Groups and the Group HABTM People. I'm trying to create a stats page that shows how many people are in a certain group. Does anybody know a quick way I can show in a table how many records belong to a certain model? I'll show some code for clarity.

Here is a method for displaying some date that I already have in place.

```
def subscribed_num
 @person = Person.all.subscribed.count
 @engaged = Person.all.count
end
```

Here is my view

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Statistics</h2>

<p class="total-number">All Engaged People: <%= @engaged %></p>
<p class='total-number'>Subscribed People: <%= @person %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Send Message", root_path %></p>
</div>
```

Now I want to use both models `People` and `Groups` to list how many people in a certain group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the count is simple, you call `.count`.

For your case (showing the number of people in a group) :

```
@group = Group.first
count = @group.people.count
```

Note that the `.count` method will alter your SQL query so that it only 
returns the count (i.e. it doesn't actually load up all your records into memory, which can be slow).

If you're not sure what I mean by this, perhaps you ought to have a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747106/how-does-rails-activerecord-chain-where-clauses-without-multiple-queries) or [this section of the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: Calling `.all` on a table with a huge number of records can be the kiss of death. Loading everything into memory might destroy your server, so it's best avoided.