# Blocks and call scope in irb behaving inconsistantly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stack-trace, irb

I've been experimenting with some of the internal rails code in Rails 4.2.7 with spring preloader and found some odd behavior of stack dumps in irb.

Consider the following code

```
def run_block
  yield
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.instantiate(*args)
    puts caller_locations
    super
  end

  def self.test_stack
    run_block {Vehicle.all}
  end
end
```

notice that I'm extending the functionality of the instantiate function (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/instantiate/class) to print out the call stack.

When I open a rails c console and run

```
run_block {puts caller_locations}
```

I get the stack trace

```
test_irb/app/models/vehicle.rb:2:in `run_block'
(irb):4:in `irb_binding'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/workspace.rb:87:in `eval'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/workspace.rb:87:in `evaluate'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/context.rb:380:in `evaluate'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:623:in `signal_status'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:486:in `block in eval_input'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:246:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `loop'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `catch'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `each_top_level_statement'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:485:in `eval_input'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:395:in `block in start'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:394:in `catch'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:394:in `start'
...
```

But running (assuming I have some rows in the db)

```
run_block {Vehicle.all}
```

I get the stack trace

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in find_by_sql'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/result.rb:51:in `block in each'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/result.rb:51:in `each'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/result.rb:51:in `each'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `map'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `block in find_by_sql'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:49:in `find_by_sql'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:639:in `exec_queries'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:515:in `load'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/activerecord-4.2.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:630:in `inspect'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/inspector.rb:109:in `block in <module:IRB>'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/inspector.rb:102:in `inspect_value'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/context.rb:384:in `inspect_last_value'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:661:in `output_value'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:490:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:623:in `signal_status'
```

which does not show that the block was nested in the `run_block` method anywhere in the trace. Running `run_block {puts Vehicle.all}` however does show the run_block function in the stack trace. As well, running `Vehicle.first` in the block shows the expected stack trace. Yet `Vehicle.test_stack` defined above shows neither the `run_block` method nor the `test_stack` method in the stack trace. Can anybody explain this inconsistency? Is this a result of ruby language constructs or something with the implementation of the `.all` method? Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. The `instantiate` stack trace doesn't show `run_block` because `instantiate` isn't *called* from within `run_block`.

Here's the deal: when you call `Vehicle.all`, it doesn't return an array of `Vehicle` objects, each of which has been instantiated; it just returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that represents the query yet to be run. Since that's the last expression in the block passed to `run_block`, it's the return value of the block, and since `yield` is the last statement in `run_block`, the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object is also the return value of that method.

However, when you call a method from IRB, it prints what was returned, in the form of the the results of calling `Object#inspect` on it, and when you call `inspect` on an ActiveRecord::Relation object, it tries to include in the output the strings that represent each object in the relation. In order to *do* that, it has to actually run the query and instantiate the Model objects, so it does, and your `instantiate` override is finally called. But that's after the `run_block` block has already exited!

Indeed, if you ran (in IRB) `run_block {Vehicle.all} ; nil` on a single line, IRB would print `nil` as the result of evaluating that, and your instantiate method would never be called at all.

When you use `run_block { puts Vehicle.all }`, then the Relation object has be actual realized for the puts, which takes place inside the block so in that case you *do* see `run_block` in the stack trace.

Comment: Wow, more complicated than expected. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @SJH the reason ActiveRecord goes to this trouble is to allow chaining calls on relations, as explained quite nicely in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747106/how-does-rails-activerecord-chain-where-clauses-without-multiple-queries