# How to understand the work flow in ruby enumerator chain

Tags: ruby, enumerator

The code below produces two different results.

```
letters = %w(e d c b a)

letters.group_by.each_with_index { |item, index| index % 3 }
#=> {0=>["e", "b"], 1=>["d", "a"], 2=>["c"]}

letters.each_with_index.group_by { |item, index| index % 3 }
#=> {0=>[["e", 0], ["b", 3]], 1=>[["d", 1], ["a", 4]], 2=>[["c", 2]]}
```

I think the execution flow is from right to left, and the data flow is from the left to right. The block should be passed as parameter from right to left.

Using `puts`, I observed that the block is executed in the inner `each`.

In the first chain, `group_by` should ask `each` for data, `each` will return the result of `index%3`, and `group_by` should process the result and yield it to another block. But how is the block passed? If the block is executed in `each`, `each` would not pass two parameters `item` and `index` but only one parameter `item`.

In the second chain, in my understanding, `each_with_index` will receive the data from `each` method first; `each` yields to `index%3`. In that case, how can `each_with_index` process `index%3`?

It seems my understanding is somehow wrong. Can anyone illustrate theses two examples with details and give the general work flow in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

## Proxy objects

Both execution and data flows are from left to right, as with any method call in Ruby.

Conceptually, it can help to read `Enumerator`s call chains from right to left, though, because they're a kind of a [proxy object](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/08/07/patterns-are-not-scary-method-missing-proxy/).

Called without block, they just remember in which order which method has been called. The method is then only really called when it's needed, for example when the `Enumerator` is converted back to an `Array` or the elements are printed on screen.

If no such method is called at the end of the chain, basically nothing happens:

```
[1,2,3].each_with_index.each_with_index.each_with_index.each_with_index
# #<Enumerator: ...>

[1,2,3].each_with_index.each_with_index.each_with_index.each_with_index.to_a
# [[[[[1, 0], 0], 0], 0], [[[[2, 1], 1], 1], 1], [[[[3, 2], 2], 2], 2]]
```

This behaviour makes it possible to work with very large streams of objects, without needing to pass huge arrays between method calls. If the output isn't needed, nothing is calculated. If 3 elements are needed at the end, only 3 elements are calculated.

The proxy pattern is heavily used in Rails, for example with `ActiveRecord::Relation` :

```
@person = Person.where(name: "Jason").where(age: 26)
```

It would be inefficient to launch 2 DB queries in this case. You can only know that at the end of the chained methods, though. Here's a related answer ([How does Rails ActiveRecord chain “where” clauses without multiple queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10747692/6419007))

## MyEnumerator

Here's a quick and dirty `MyEnumerator` class. It might help you understand the logic for the method calls in your question:

```
class MyEnumerator < Array
  def initialize(*p)
    @methods = []
    @blocks = []
    super
  end

  def group_by(&b)
    save_method_and_block(__method__, &b)
    self
  end

  def each_with_index(&b)
    save_method_and_block(__method__, &b)
    self
  end

  def to_s
    "MyEnumerable object #{inspect} with methods : #{@methods} and #{@blocks}"
  end

  def apply
    result = to_a
    puts "Starting with #{result}"
    @methods.zip(@blocks).each do |m, b|
      if b
        puts "Apply method #{m} with block #{b} to #{result}"
      else
        puts "Apply method #{m} without block to #{result}"
      end
      result = result.send(m, &b)
    end
    result
  end

  private

  def save_method_and_block(method, &b)
    @methods << method
    @blocks << b
  end
end

letters = %w[e d c b a]

puts MyEnumerator.new(letters).group_by.each_with_index { |_, i| i % 3 }.to_s
# MyEnumerable object ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"] with methods : [:group_by, :each_with_index] and [nil, #<Proc:0x00000001da2518@my_enumerator.rb:35>]
puts MyEnumerator.new(letters).group_by.each_with_index { |_, i| i % 3 }.apply
# Starting with ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
# Apply method group_by without block to ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
# Apply method each_with_index with block #<Proc:0x00000000e2cb38@my_enumerator.rb:42> to #<Enumerator:0x00000000e2c610>
# {0=>["e", "b"], 1=>["d", "a"], 2=>["c"]}

puts MyEnumerator.new(letters).each_with_index.group_by { |_item, index| index % 3 }.to_s
# MyEnumerable object ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"] with methods : [:each_with_index, :group_by] and [nil, #<Proc:0x0000000266c220@my_enumerator.rb:48>]
puts MyEnumerator.new(letters).each_with_index.group_by { |_item, index| index % 3 }.apply
# Apply method each_with_index without block to ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
# Apply method group_by with block #<Proc:0x0000000266bd70@my_enumerator.rb:50> to #<Enumerator:0x0000000266b938>
# {0=>[["e", 0], ["b", 3]], 1=>[["d", 1], ["a", 4]], 2=>[["c", 2]]}
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your great explanation and sample code.After running your sample, I see after the first apply, applying the group by to the [e,d,c,b,a] produce a enumerator which is linked to the method group_by. In that step, the enumerator is not executed.   In the second apply, applying the each_index_with to the first result(enumerator), each_index_with produce such a result :'{0=>["e","b"]....}'. Without any block passed through, how does the group_by know how to group? The process from enumerator to '{0=>["e","b"]...}' is mysterious!