# How to fix this N+1. Rails. Also, why are N+1 queries so bad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

So I just want to make sure that this is an N+1 query and I want to know how to fix it. ON a high level, where am I losing the most time in an N+1 query? Is it the request over the network to the database url that is costing me the most time? Or is the actual query **IN** the database that is costing me the most time?

Say we have this:

```
products = Product.where(user_id: user.id)  # This is one network database query right?

products.select { |product| !product.restrictions.map(&:state).includes?(user.address.state) } 
# restriction is another table. We're trying to filter out products that are restricted to the user's state.
```

**Questions**

1. So technically, is this an N+1 query? It is because we're making 1 query to get all products for the user **AND** another to filter out the restricted products by comparing the product's restrictions by state to the user's state.
2. So, on a high level, what can I do? Can I eager load the restrictions table in my first query? Or should I just make one trip and do everything in the first query? Are these my two options?

**Update**

So assume I did `Product.includes(:restrictions).where(user_id: user.id)`, this is all stil oone query right?

Is this also one query if this was all in one method:

```
products = Product.where(user_id: user.id)`
products.includes(:restrictions).select do |product|
!product.restrictions.map(&:state_name).include?("CT")
end
```

Comment: yes, this is an N+1 query. You can easily observe this in your server log.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great articles [like this one](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/) that go into this in more detail, but the general concept is that any time you're iterating through a list and making queries based on that list then you're performing an N+1 query. You're losing the most time over the network, but also each query comes with a set amount of overhead.

Question 1. Yes this is an N+1 query.

You're making an N+1 query when you return each product and then for each product you return whether it is restricted or not. You can typically recognize them because you are iterating through queries like you do above with `products.select { |product| }`. This could potentially product hundreds of queries when you could just batch them instead.

In your example, you are returning an array of products and making another request to filter out the list.

Your code currently produces SQL similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE user_id=1;
```

and then performs another filter where you're checking product restrictions which produces these queries:

```
SELECT restrictions FROM products WHERE product_id=1, user_id=1, state="x";
SELECT restrictions FROM products WHERE product_id=2, user_id=1, state="x";
SELECT restrictions FROM products WHERE product_id=3, user_id=1, state="x";
...
```

Question 2. You should just do this all in one query and batch the results. This is psuedocode, but you get the idea:

```
products = Product.where(user_id: @user).select(restrictions: state)`
```

Response to your update: That will still create two queries. The method just runs from the top to bottom. The only way to make it only create one query is to use and chain the provided Rails ORM methods which create proxy objects and then create a single query. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10747692/1336988

Comment: That will give me the restricted products no? So a `product` has many restrictions and a `Restriction` is a state (`Restriction` has a name and cateogry column corresponding to 'CT' and 'US State')

Comment: It was psuedocode. The point is that you need to chain your Rails queries together to produce one SQL query. And in regards to your update - even if it's just in one method it will produce multiple queries unless it is chained.

Answer (score 1):

N+1 queries are a common performance issue in Rails applications, where the database is queried multiple times for related records, resulting in slower response times.

It’s important to know how to identify, fix and avoid it in the future.

**Possible steps can be like this:**

- Identify the N+1 queries
- Analyze the queries
- Use eager loading
- Use joins
- Use counter_cache
- Test and measure

By following these steps, you can identify, debug, and fix N+1 queries in your Rails application, and improve the performance of your application.

There is a big article, where you can find a detailed explanation of each of these steps - https://ruby.mobidev.biz/posts/how-to-find-debug-fix-n+1-queries-in-rails/

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

After @codelitt's answer, here is how you solve this.
You should call

`products = Product.includes(:restrictions).where(user_id: user.id) // or you can write the includes in your scope`

This will fetch all the related `restriction` records with the products in the memory. So, in the next line, there won't be a bunch of db query which is costly. Rather it will fetch the records from the memory.