# Rails Query Multiple Params From Same Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I search for multiple params?  I have checkboxes in my view, so if multiple checkboxes are selected, I would like all the `params` selected to be chosen.  I can currently only get the search to work with one `param` with code below.

There is a `has_many` to `has_many` association between `car` model and `colour_collection` model.

Controller:

```
@cars = car.joins(:colour_collections).where("colour_collections.name = ?", params[:colour_collection])
```

logs show this if two colours selected (e.g. red and green) creating duplicates in the resulting querie:

```
(0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "colour_collections"
  ColourCollection Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "colour_collections".* FROM "colour_collections"
  Car Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "car_colour_collections" ON "car_colour_collections"."car_id" = "cars"."id" INNER JOIN "colour_collections" ON "colour_collections"."id" = "car_colour_collections"."colour_collection_id" WHERE "colour_collections"."name" IN ('Subtle', 'Intermediate') ORDER BY "cars"."created_at" DESC
  CarAttachment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "car_attachments".* FROM "car_attachments" WHERE "car_attachments"."car_id" = $1 ORDER BY "car_attachments"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["car_id", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "car_attachments".* FROM "car_attachments" WHERE "car_attachments"."car_id" = $1 ORDER BY "car_attachments"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["car_id", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CarAttachment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "car_attachments".* FROM "car_attachments" WHERE "car_attachments"."car_id" = $1 ORDER BY "car_attachments"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["car_id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "car_attachments".* FROM "car_attachments" WHERE "car_attachments"."car_id" = $1 ORDER BY "car_attachments"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["car_id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for multiple values in a single column for example

```
params[:colour_collection] = ['red','green','blue']
```

Then you would expect your query to look like this

```
SELECT * FROM cars c 
INNER JOIN colour_collections s 
WHERE s.name IN ('red','green','blue');
```

In this case the corresponding ActiveRecord statement would look like this

```
Car.
joins(:colour_collections).
where(colour_collections: { name: params[:colour_collection] })
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.  Question - I'm currently getting duplicates of each item in views - so if item has both attribute colour 'green' and 'blue' and both coloured are searched in one query, I think it's showing twice because one is returning green results and other is returning blue results.

Comment: Could you update your question to share an example of the data table related to the scenario you are talking about ?

Comment: Ok - just added.

Comment: I meant an example of the data stored in your table. A couple of rows maybe

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5 comes with an `or` method but Rails 4 does not have the `or` method, so you can use plain SQL query in Rails 4.

In Rails 4 :

```
@cars = car.
        joins(:colour_collections).
        where("colour_collections.name = ? or colour_collections.type = ?", params[:colour_collection], params[:type])
```

In Rails 5 :

```
@cars = car.
        joins(:colour_collections).
        where("colour_collections.name = ?", params[:colour_collection]).or(car.joins(:colour_collections).where("colour_collections.type = ?", params[:type]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`@cars = car.joins(:colour_collections).where("colour_collections.name = ?", params[:colour_collection]).where("cars.make = ?", params[:make])`

More discussion on chaining [How does Rails ActiveRecord chain "where" clauses without multiple queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747106/how-does-rails-activerecord-chain-where-clauses-without-multiple-queries)

Comment: Does it matter if it's searching same table/column, meaning in your example, there's `colour_collection` and `make` - I'm looking for if someone chooses 2 colours.  I tried this but nothing...here's what I tried `@w_artisans = car.joins(:colour_collections).where("colour_collections.name = ?", params[:colour_collection]).where("colour_collections.name = ?", params[:colour_collection])` - I get this error `PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type record`  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to use `OR` or `AND`. There are multiple ways of achieving this but simple example is 
`Article.where(trashed: true).where(trashed: false)`
the sql generated will be
 
`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE 'trashed' = 1 AND 'trashed' = 0`

`Foo.where(foo: 'bar').or.where(bar: 'bar')` This is norm in Rails 5 or simply
`Foo.where('foo= ? OR bar= ?', 'bar', 'bar')`

Comment: Does it matter if it's searching the same table/column twice.  So instead of `Foo.where('foo= ? OR bar= ?', 'bar', 'bar')`, it would be `Foo.where('foo= ? OR foo= ?', 'bar', 'bar')`.  I've tried this using `params[:colour_collection]` as the params ('bar') and I get an error message with `Invalid Statement`. When I try `#{params[:colour_collection]}`, it finally works, but only searches one item still.  Any thoughts?

Comment: So someone can essentially search for 2 colours by checking 2 boxes.