# When is an ActiveRecord query executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had a confusion about how Ruby executes a query:

Lets suppose we have two methods:

```
def meet1
   user = User.all
end
```

everytime I call this method I get a query running which says:

> 'User Load (18.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "users"."banned" = 'f' AND "roles"."description" = 'gogetter''

It means that it queries the users...

lets suppose I have another method:

```
def meet2
  user = User.all
  user.to_sql
end
```

when I call this it returned me the SQL format of that query:

So my question is in the first method the query gets executed but does the query gets executed in the second method? Or its just showing me the end result without executing the query because I never used it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`user = User.all` does nothing but create a potential query, and `spawn` a copy of it into `user`. This follows the "Builder Pattern"; `user` could then say `user.joins(...)`, or `user.order(...)`, to build a different potential query. They both return a `spawn`ed copy of the query.

What you do with `meet1` triggers the actual hit to the database. I suspect that something as innocuous as `p meet1`, or even your IRB shell, could evaluate the `spawn`ed potential database query as an `Enumeration`, which then hits the database.

Answer (score 5):

I would like you too have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10747692/3759158)

> when you call `User.all` it returns `User::ActiveRecord_Relation` object, and by itself this object does not issue a database query. It's where you use this object that matters.

so when meet1 is called it issues the query but in case of `meet2` `User.all` issues relational object and `user.to_sql` issues the query related to database.

You can see same thing happens when you try to chain multiple filters based on condition

```
u = User.all
u = u.where(name: "Hello") if any_condition?
u = u.where(last_name: 'world') if any_other_condition?
```

in such cases the in any_condition? and any_other_condition? is true it does only one query merging all 3 thing .all and all the where conditions.

I would like you have a look at [blog here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2010/10/24/the-chain-gang/) it shows some `kickers` methods which will make you a bit more clear about the way.

Comment: One potential point of confusion - if you ran this in irb or rails console, after each line the rails console will try to evaluate the result, causing it to execute.

Comment: @user3342930 IRB and Rails Console both uses IRB under the hood. IRB is  Read-Eval-Print Loop so as soon as user type anything that is considered as the last statement (unless we talk about blocks) and hence Rails console and IRB both issues query directly.
This link is very useful to understand IRB
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-irb-to-explore-ruby