# rails find_by returns incorrect record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where a `User` creates a `Transaction` to purchase an `Item` from a different `User`. I am suddenly having difficulty with the `find_by` in one method on `Item`. I want to find the very first `Transaction` involving the `Item` on which it is called, and I want to further limit that result by searching against a number of invalid states.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
 def first_find
  Transaction.find_by("item_id = ? AND recipient_id = ? AND state != ? OR state != ? OR state != ?", self.id, author.id, :ignored, :declined, :unapproved)
 end
end
```

What this does, no matter what, is return the very first `Transaction` in my db. This is not expected behavior. So in console if I go like `t = Transaction.last` to cache `Transaction` id #5 (which has an `item_id` of 7 and a `recipient_id` of 4), and then call `t.item.first_find`, I would presumably get `Transaction` #5. The SQL output for this is query is `Transaction Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE (item_id = 7 AND recipient_id = 4 AND state != 'ignored' OR state != 'declined' OR state != 'unapproved') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]`.

Which is great! That's what I want from the output. But to my confusion, it returns this:

```
#<Transaction id: 2, sender_id: 1, recipient_id: 2, item_id: 9 ..... >
```

Does anyone have any idea why? Thanks!

---

**Edit 1**

So I think I've solved it? I've had this problem before where putting too many search params into the `where` clause messes it up for some reason.

So while this does *not* work

```
Transaction.find_by("item_id = ? AND recipient_id = ? AND state != ? OR state != ? OR state != ?", self.id, author.id, :ignored, :declined, :unapproved)
```

This does

```
Transaction.where("item_id = ? AND recipient_id = ?", self.id, author.id).where("state != ? OR state != ? OR state != ?", :ignored, :declined, :unapproved).first
```

I'm not entirely sure why, though. Does anyone know?

---

**Edit 2**

The AND operators should be separate from the OR operators.

Comment: Have you tried the same query in the SQL console?

Comment: @BradWerth what's the SQL console? i've tried it in the rails console, if that's what you meant

Comment: If you are using mongoid you cant expect the ordering before hand. Its totally random. You need to define sorting and limit 1 manually

Comment: @Oshanz i'm using postgresql

Comment: Also i think you need to group "or" conditions seperate from "and"s ex:  a and b and (c or d or e)

Comment: yup yup, i just figured that one out, but i didn't pick up on the fact that the commonality between the two `where` clauses is: one is solely AND while the other is solely OR

Comment: if you write that out into an answer, i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answering why.
that's how SQL [operator precedence](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Language/Operators#Operator_precedence) works. more explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or#1241158). so when you break it to another "where" clause that [builds a new relation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10747692/3011280), which is the result of filtering the current relation according to the conditions in the arguments. the [source code is here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/where_clause.rb).

let me show other solutions.

1.

```
    Transaction.where(item_id: self.id, recipient_id: author.id).where.not(state: [:ignored, :declined, :unapproved]).first
```

2.

```
recipient_transactions = Transaction.where(item_id: self.id, recipient_id: author.id)
active_transactions = Transaction.where.not(state: [:ignored, :declined, :unapproved])
result = recipient_transactions.merge(active_transactions).first # this buils a single query
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `where` clause instead of using `find_by`,

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  def first_find
    Transaction.where("item_id = ? AND recipient_id = ? AND state != ? OR state != ? OR state != ?", self.id, author.id, :ignored, :declined, :unapproved)
  end
end
```

this will return `ActiveRecord::Relation`(record collections) instead of just one record if you using find statement

Comment: My goal is to find the *very first* record meeting those conditions, not a collection. I suppose I could do `Transaction.where(bla bla).first` but both still produce the same confusing and unexpected result.

Comment: You could use multiple `or, and where` clauses because there's some operator precedence going on over there in the query.