# ActiveRecord, method chaining and request execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, method-chaining

I'm currently trying to understand how does ActiveRecord work to chain the conditions methods and then execute the sql request.

Understanding methods chaining is pretty easy and everything I thought is nicely explained and resumed here [here](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/method-chaining-and-lazy-evaluation-in-ruby/).

However, there is something I still can't figure out and that the above article does not explain: how does ActiveRecord know when to execute the SQL request.

For example, if I code `User.where(some_column: "hello").limit(5)`, ActiveRecord will instantiate a query builder, set the conditions about the `some_column` value and the limited number of results.

But, after executing the `.limit(5)`, it also executes the request and returns the result: how can ActiveRecord know? How can it know that it is the final condition method and that it needs to return a result? Does it execute an SQL request at each chained condition?

In the article I've posted above, the author was tricking by calling a final method, `each` which was executing the request and returning the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3 ActiveRecord method chaining, under the hood](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493904/rails-3-activerecord-method-chaining-under-the-hood)

Comment: Check out http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database and http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#understanding-the-method-chaining

Comment: This is better explained [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough?view=asciicast). `to_a` is not implicitly called: it is called from the override of the inspect method. It makes sense now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`limit(5)` is not more special than `where`, in fact it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` like `where` does. You can swap the order of the chain to prove it.

```
User.where(some_column: "hello").limit(5)
User.limit(5).where(some_column: "hello")
```

What happens is that there are certain methods that called explicitly (for example in the controller) or implicitly (in the CLI) triggers the execution of the query. These methods are for example:

- Enumerable methods such as `each`, `select`, etc
- Explicit casting methods such as `to_a`
- Query methods such as `first`, `last`, `take`

Whenever one of these methods is called implicitly or explicitly then the query is executed.